# Convert Spotify.com `Track` to YouTube Track

Tags: api, youtube, spotify

I have implemented the spotify api succefully and fetched all tracks url       using there API.

But The requirement is that:

Search that spotify `track` on youtube and get url for same as of youtube.

I have found one website from where it is possible.

Please have look:: http://spo2tu.be/

But I would like to implement same logic on my website backend script.

Do anyone give me some idea or solution on same?

Comment: Start a bounty, to get answer.